# .submit() does not work if table row deleted

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the function below which deletes a row from a table. If this is the last function I called, my form .submit() call does not work. But only if this is the *last* function to be called. I can delete a row and still submit the form if some other function is called after it (such as a duplicate row function I have).

I have no idea why it will not work.

```
      function deleteRow(element) {
          event.preventDefault();
          if (document.getElementById('linesTable').lastChild.children.length > 1) {
              document.getElementById('linesTable').deleteRow(element.target.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);
              updateTotals()
          } else {
              alert('There must be at least one line.')
          }
      }
```

Comment: Can you show the HTML markup for the form, and the eventListeners you have registered for the form for the deleteRow and submit buttons? That would make this example easier to help you with.

Comment: Is it recursion? What is the element? Maybe event ..
Where is the delete actually?

Comment: I think `parentNode.rowIndex` is not correct `parentNode[rowIndex]` is correct??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are preventing the default event when submitting

`event.preventDefault();`

remove that if not needed or reverse it after finishing with this function.